# how to parse xml as an argument to a shell script

Tags: shell-script, xml

this is the sample xml file I have, I need to get max_size as an output?

I tried using xlimit and xpath , both not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-service>
   <service_info name="dummyapp" version="5.0"
   <object name="WebApplications">
      <item Location="dummyapp/ear/dummyapp.ear" name="dummy"/>
   </object>
   <object name="jdbc_oracle_nonxa">
      <item db_name="MYDB1" db_user="dummyapp_user" global_trans="None" initial_size="10" jndi_name="dummyapp-aty-ds" max_size="25" name="dummyapp-aty-ds" statement_cache_size="10"/>
</object>
```

Comment: Hello, please take the time to consult the [tour] to know and understand better how works Stackexchange. Could you please try to provide a clear explanation of what you have, what you want what you've try and what's not working as expected. There's no chance anyone will be able to help you with such a question without any information

Comment: *this is the sample xml file* - and where is it?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Since the formatter hides XML tags unless they are indented by 4 spaces, the XML was "invisible" (but there).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the XML is well formed, such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-service>
  <service_info name="dummyapp" version="5.0"/>
  <object name="WebApplications">
    <item Location="dummyapp/ear/dummyapp.ear" name="dummy"/>
  </object>
  <object name="jdbc_oracle_nonxa">
    <item db_name="MYDB1" db_user="dummyapp_user" global_trans="None" initial_size="10" jndi_name="dummyapp-aty-ds" max_size="25" name="dummyapp-aty-ds" statement_cache_size="10"/>
  </object>
</weblogic-service>
```

(I've closed tags that were not closed in the question)

... then the following will output `25` (for this example):

```
xml sel -t -v '//item/@max_size' -nl file.xml
```

This is using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to get the value of the `max_value` attribute of all `item` nodes. The `-nl` at the end inserts a newline after the output.

If you need to be more specific and only look at the `item` node in the `object` node whose `name` is `jdbc_oracle_nonxa`:

```
xml sel -t -v '//object[@name="jdbc_oracle_nonxa"]/item/@max_size' -nl file.xml
```

Note that XMLStarlet is installed as `xmlstarlet` rather than `xml` on some systems.

---

Using `xmllint` (no newline at end of output):

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//object[@name="jdbc_oracle_nonxa"]/item/@max_size)' file.xml
```

Comment: getting below error-bash: xml: command not found

Comment: @user2576747 That's because you don't have XMLstarlet installed, or it is installed but as `xmlstarlet` rather than as `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Often, you are much faster, but less secure, with sed or grep:

```
sed -E -n 's/.*max_size="([0-9]+)".*/\1/p' sample-4.xml 
25
```

or grep:

```
grep -Eo 'max_size="[0-9]+" ' sample-4.xml | grep -Eo "[0-9]+"
25
```

It doesn't validate the xml and might pick commented code without recognizing. If you look at the screen, and get two results, you might notice, but if it is used in an automated process, it is error prone.

Sometimes you have written the program, generating the xml, so you know, whether it might output comments or max_size="..." in a different, unwanted context. If you know the limits, there is nothing wrong with sed, grep or awk, except that they prevent you from learning the beautiful xmlstarlet-syntax. :)